# iptables loses source address when forwarding to an internal virtual machine (Proxmox)

Tags: iptables, virtualization, nat, proxmox

I have a Proxmox hypervisor. This proxmox is running a VM with HAProxy load balancer.

I am now trying to forward to this HAProxy via iptables port 80 and 443. Unfortunately the source address is lost and every request comes from 192.168.0.1 (Proxmox).

Am I missing a setting or is my forwarding wrong?
Forward:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i enp2s0 -d 148.XXX.XX.XX -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.140:80
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i enp2s0 -d 148.XXX.XX.XX -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.140:443

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.140 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.140 --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: The rules you posted are changing only the destination address (```DNAT``` target), not the source address. This happens somewhere else...

Comment: Please add output of `iptables-save` to the question.